# Prove for entropy of a source with m > 2 channel symbols.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, logarithms, information-theory, entropy

I'm trying to prove that a source with $m>2$ symbols (source symbols), where a symbol has a probability of $\alpha\ll 1/m$ and the rest of the symbols have the same probability has a entropy of:

$$H(X)= \log_2(m-1)+\alpha \log_2(1/\alpha)$$

Please, any help will be accepted!!

Comment: I don't even know where to start... Is the first time I see this expression **α≪1/m** as a probability.

Answer (score 0):

So $m-1$ of the symbols have probability $(1-\alpha)/(m-1)$, which is approximately $1/(m-1)$. These symbols contribute with the sum
$$
-(m-1)\frac{1-\alpha}{m-1}\log_2\frac{1-\alpha}{m-1},
$$
which is then approximately equal to what?

Comment: But the problem states that the symbol have a probabilty of α≪1/m. Where do you take the m-1 probabilty from?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: There is well known and useful result: if you have two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ whose supports (alphabets) don't overlap, and you make a "mix" of them $X=X_1$ with prob. $p$, $X=X_2$ with prob. $1-p$, then the entropy of the mixing is $H(X)=p \, H(X_1)+(1-p)\,H(X_2) + h(p)$ where $h(\cdot)$ is the binary entropy function.

Hint 2: The formula you quote is *not* exact, it's an approximation that it's only valid for $\alpha \ll 1/m$, it should be $H(X) \approx \log_2(m-1)+\alpha \log_2(1/\alpha)$

Just write down the exact form of $H(X)$ (I gave one -just one- possible way to do this in my first hint), and see what happens to it when $\alpha \ll 1/m$

Comment: Hi think I understand your point, I've done problems before where I was asked to prove entropy of BSC with probabilities of α and 1-α, where the probabilites of receiving the message was 1-p and p. But I don't understand what a probabilty of α≪1/m means, what does it have to do with the channel having more than 2 source symbols?

Comment: Do you mind explaining what really means the term α≪1/m? All I know, that's related to binomial probabilty, and that when's used as m≪1, really means that m is really really small. Thank you sir..

Comment: Hi, today I realized that the **α≪1/m** has to do with Poisson distribution but have not found a way to prove it.. I know the binary entropy function but I can't figure out how to match it with the $H(x_1)$ and $H(x_2)$ from the formula and prove the $H(X)=log2⁡(m−1)+αlog2⁡(1/α)$ equation.